# Prediction of future dividend dates and dividend amounts in R

Tags: r, predictive-models

I have the dividends data of a company from 1987 to 2021. Using this data, I want to predict the future dividend dates for the next 5 years. Also, I want to predict the future dividend amounts this company is expected to distribute on these dates.

```r
dividends_dt <- structure(list(ex_date = c("2021-08-06", "2021-05-07", "2021-02-05", 
"2020-11-06", "2020-08-07", "2020-05-08", "2020-02-07", "2019-11-07", 
"2019-08-09", "2019-05-10", "2019-02-08", "2018-11-08", "2018-08-10", 
"2018-05-11", "2018-02-09", "2017-11-10", "2017-08-10", "2017-05-11", 
"2017-02-09", "2016-11-03", "2016-08-04", "2016-05-05", "2016-02-04", 
"2015-11-05", "2015-08-06", "2015-05-07", "2015-02-05", "2014-11-06", 
"2014-08-07", "2014-05-08", "2014-02-06", "2013-11-06", "2013-08-08", 
"2013-05-09", "2013-02-07", "2012-11-07", "2012-08-09", "1995-11-21", 
"1995-08-16", "1995-05-26", "1995-02-13", "1994-11-18", "1994-08-15", 
"1994-05-27", "1994-02-07", "1993-11-19", "1993-08-16", "1993-05-28", 
"1993-02-12", "1992-11-30", "1992-08-17", "1992-06-01", "1992-02-14", 
"1991-11-18", "1991-08-19", "1991-05-20", "1991-02-15", "1990-11-16", 
"1990-08-20", "1990-05-21", "1990-02-16", "1989-11-17", "1989-08-21", 
"1989-05-22", "1989-02-17", "1988-11-21", "1988-08-15", "1988-05-16", 
"1988-02-12", "1987-11-17", "1987-08-10", "1987-05-11"), frequency = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), cash_amount = c(0.22, 0.22, 0.205, 0.205, 
0.205, 0.205, 0.1925, 0.1925, 0.1925, 0.1925, 0.1825, 0.1825, 
0.1825, 0.1825, 0.1575, 0.1575, 0.1575, 0.1575, 0.1425, 0.1425, 
0.1425, 0.1425, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.1175, 0.1175, 0.1175, 
0.1175, 0.1089285714, 0.1089285714, 0.1089285714, 0.1089285714, 
0.0946428571, 0.0946428571, 0.0946428571, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 
0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 
0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 
0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 
0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0009821429, 
0.0009821429, 0.0009821429, 0.0009821429, 0.0008928572, 0.0008928572, 
0.0008928572, 0.0008928572, 0.0007142857, 0.0007142857, 0.0007142857, 
0.0007142857, 0.0005357143, 0.0005357143)), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

       ex_date frequency  cash_amount
 1: 2021-08-06         4 0.2200000000
 2: 2021-05-07         4 0.2200000000
 3: 2021-02-05         4 0.2050000000
 4: 2020-11-06         4 0.2050000000
 5: 2020-08-07         4 0.2050000000
 6: 2020-05-08         4 0.2050000000
 7: 2020-02-07         4 0.1925000000
 8: 2019-11-07         4 0.1925000000
...
...
```

I have used the regression below to predict the dividend dates/ amounts based on the trend line, but am getting the wrong results.

Here is what I have tried

```r
library(data.table)
dividends_dt[, year := year(ex_date)]
dividend_summary = dividends_dt[, .(div_per_year = sum(cash_amount, na.rm = T)), by = .(year)]
setorder(dividend_summary, div_per_year)
dividend_summary[, div_growth_rate := 100 * (div_per_year - shift(div_per_year, type = "lag"))/ shift(div_per_year, type = "lag")]
> dividend_summary

    year div_per_year div_growth_rate
 1: 1987  0.001785714              NA
 2: 1988  0.003035714       69.999999
 3: 1989  0.003660714       20.588242
 4: 1990  0.004017857        9.756095
 5: 1995  0.004285714        6.666665
 6: 1994  0.004285714        0.000000
 7: 1993  0.004285714        0.000000
 8: 1992  0.004285714        0.000000
 9: 1991  0.004285714        0.000000
10: 2012  0.189285714     4316.666547
11: 2013  0.421428571      122.641509
12: 2014  0.461428571        9.491525
13: 2015  0.507500000        9.984520
14: 2016  0.557500000        9.852217
15: 2017  0.615000000       10.313901
16: 2021  0.645000000        4.878049
17: 2018  0.705000000        9.302326
18: 2019  0.760000000        7.801418
19: 2020  0.807500000        6.250000

lm.fit = glm(data = dividend_summary, formula = div_growth_rate ~ year)

# Creating a new data table with future years to predict their dividends
new.dt <- data.table(year=c(2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026))
> predict(lm.fit, new.dt)

       1        2        3        4        5 
419.4077 429.2242 439.0408 448.8573 458.6739
```

As you can see, the result is not consistent with the past trend.

Also, I could not figure out any way to predict the future dates when the dividend will be distributed.

I will appreciate it if someone can provide pointers to solve this problem.

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at any textbook about predictive modeling. [An Introduction to Statistical Learning with R](https://www.statlearning.com) is available for free and is excellent.

Comment: A simple linear regression model is a poor choice. There is no problem with your code. The problem is with your choice of model for this data.

Comment: ...(b) It's better now that you've showed an attempt, but your question is still incredibly broad. There's no "right answer" for what model you should use for this - there are many many options depending on how much data you have, what assumptions you are willing to make, etc. You tried one of the simplest options. For example, you could look into quantile regression, bayesian methods, maybe some data cleaning and outlier removal... there are many many options.

Comment: To make a good model it's good to understand a few possible models, when they should be applied, their assumptions, and diagnostics to assess those assumptions. I can glance at your data and see that most values between 0 and 10 and one value over 4000 will cause problems. But there's no single fix for that. Similarly, are the years of 0s an error in the data or real? Is linear over year at all reasonable? There's no quick fix. And walking you through all those questions and possibilities is too much for a simple Q&A site.

Comment: This is the real dividends data of Apple stock. There were years when Apple did not increase the dividend and that caused the dividend growth rate to be zero.

Comment: ...indicating that a model assuming a linear trend is probably a poor choice.